# arrow function not working but using function the old way works

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I'm trying to be all cool and modern and use arrow function es6 js but failed at the first attempt.

Why does this arrow function sumRange NOT work:

```
    var output = sumRange(3);
    console.log(output);    

sumRange = (num) => {
            if(num == 1) return 1;
            console.log(num);
            return  num + sumRange(num - 1);
        }
```

But here the function DOES work:

```
   var output = sumRange(3);
console.log(output);

function sumRange(num){
    if(num == 1) return 1;
    console.log(num)
    return num + sumRange(num - 1);
}
```

Comment: `function` declaration statements are treated as if they appeared at the very top of the enclosing scope.  If you move the first two lines to *after* the point at which you initialize `sumRange`, your first bit of code would work.

Comment: `sumRange = function (num) { ... }` won't work either

Comment: See the linked question's answers, they apply just as much to arrow function expressions as to traditional function expressions.

Comment: The first thing to do in this situation is to look at the error in the error in the web console, which would give you a hint about what the problem is. (In your case: `Ucaught ReferenceError: someRange is not defined`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring the `console.log()` after the declartion of arrow function.

**Note**: that you are not declaring function with any keyword. You should use `let` `var` or `const` to declare the function.

```js
let sumRange = (num) => {
    if(num == 1) return 1;
    console.log(num);
    return  num + sumRange(num - 1);
}

var output = sumRange(3);
console.log(output);
```

Why does second one works?

Because that is [function statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting). And it can be used even before it declaration.

> Function declarations in JavaScript are hoisted to the top of the enclosing function or global scope. **You can use the function before you declared it**

Comment: *"In global scope its fine..."* No, it isn't, implicit globals are never fine. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I didn't know about that can you please explain a little.

Comment: See [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) on my anemic little blog. Even if at global scope, declare your variables. (Best: Don't create global variables at all.)